# Queue in animation not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was experimenting with something like scroll to bottom of the page using jquery along with animating the button clicked. The code is working fine in chrome but runs unexpected in firefox and Internet explorer 11. Please help.

Here is my js.

```
var dh=$(document).height(), dw=$(window).width(), hh=$("header").outerHeight(), fh=$("footer").outerHeight(), bw=$(".buttontodown img").attr('width');

$(".buttontodown img").on("click", function(){

    $(".click2").fadeOut(1000);

    $(".buttontodown").animate({
    top:($("footer").offset().top-bw-20)
    }, {"queue": false, "duration": 1000});

    $(".buttontodown img").animate({ textIndent: 180 }, {
        step: function(now,fx)
        {
            $(this).css({
                '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                'transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                '-ms-transform':'rotate('+now+'deg)'});
                },
                duration:1000
        }, {"queue": false, "duration": 1000});

    $("html,body").animate({"scrollTop":$("footer").offset().top}, {"queue": false, "duration": 1000});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour, and what is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Are you saying the behavior in Firefox and IE11 is not as expected or your experiencing some js errors ?

Comment: I wana say that in chrome all the 3 animations are working at the same time but in firefox and IE11 the scroll animation(last animation) is running first and second animate function after it.

I want all the 3 to run at the same time.

Comment: Well, without any example link we can't help you

Comment: I am sorry but i don't have any hosting to host them. I can rather explain my page structure.**buttontodown** is a div that contains an image which is to be clicked to navigate to the bottom of the page.**click2** is a random paragraph text which is faded on the click of the image.Now the image itself animates to the bottom of the page along with the page.The 1st fade function is to fade out the that random text, 1st animate function is to animate the image to the bottom of the page, 2nd animate function is to animate the image rotate 180 deg and finally the 3rd animate is to scroll the page.